# Excel needing to fill blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having some issues with trying to fill in the blanks in my excel document, the code I have wrote only works for one blank but doesn't work when there are multiple blanks and I want to still reference the last value shown.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D11),OFFSET(D11,-1,0),D11)
```

However throughout my document the number of blanks in a row can vary from 25 blanks to 2 blanks

To explain slightly better the example below I would like both blanks to display 0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes

E.g.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Paula

Comment: I dint get your question properly. Are you looking at filling all the cells in a range to 0 if the cell is blank?

Comment: @siva in this occasion yes but it will change throughout the document e.g another one is 0 Days 0 Hours 15 Minutes and I have 8 records that need to be changed to this number

Answer (score 0):

It is the OFFSET(D11,-1,0) part that is giving you the issue. If you know that the first occurrence will definitely be filled in just use that reference instead: 
    =IF(ISBLANK(D11),D$2,D11)

Comment: the only issue with this is that the value I need to use constantly changes so it wont ever be statically one value

Answer (score 0):

You need the last number (aka datetime) from D1:D11.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D11), INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1e99, D$1:D11)), D11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help I managed to find another way round it by highlighting the entire column selecting special and blanks press = and then hold down Ctrl click on the last cell with information in it and then pressing enter.

This copys the last number and fills down until the number changes again.